# Getting value of an AutoProperty that has no getter using PropertyInfo.GetValue

Tags: .net, reflection, propertyinfo

I am trying to get the value of a string property in a unit test. The problem is that the property has no getter. The property is also declared as an AutoProperty and has no backing field.

I am trying to use PropertyInfo.GetValue(...) in the System.Reflection namespace. However I get System.ArgumentException : Property Get method was not found.

I do not own the code of that type so I am unable to add a getter to the property.

How does one get the value of such a property?

Comment: Could you clarify what it means to get the "value" of a property that has *no* getter? That doesn't make sense, to me at least.

Comment: Btw, auto-implemented properties must define a get *and* a set. Are you sure this isn't the case of a *private* getter rather than *no* getter at all?

Comment: Post code that reproduces this problem.

Comment: @Ani of course you are quite correct. I was in such a hurry as we are under time pressure. I interpreted the display of the property in Object Broweser as an Autoproperty where it just displays PropertyName { set; } to indicate that the property has only a setter. I opened it up in reflector which I should have done earlier and indeed it has a backing field so actually it becomes easy to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

You would somehow need to find the backing field that was auto-generated by compiler using Reflection. And then, using its `FieldInfo` you will be able to read its value. And I am not sure if it is possible at all.

OK, I have the solution:

With following class,

```
public class TestClass
{
    public String TestProperty { private get; set; }
}
```

and following extension method,

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static Object GetPropertyValue(this Object obj, String propertyName)
    {
        if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj", "`obj` cannot be null");

        var fields = from f in obj.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                     where f.Name.Contains(String.Format("<{0}>", propertyName))
                     select f;

        if (fields.Any())
        {
            return fields.First().GetValue(obj);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

You can achieve what you want by using following code:

```
TestClass obj = new TestClass() { TestProperty = "Test Value" };
Object value = obj.GetPropertyValue("TestProperty"); // value = "Test Value"
```

Comment: Many thanks decyclone thats a really nice solution. I was however wrong in my question. It turns out that the property did have a backing field, but I did not see it. Fantastic solution that you posted. And it did help the quick resolution of my problem. Thanks for your effort and apologies for my initial mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The property will have a backing field, it's just that we don't know it's name (and it's name will not be a valid identifier). If this is for a one-off task, then you might do well to crack it open using [.NET reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) and find the field that's being set by the setter.

I don't think there's anything you can do via Reflection (unless you want to parse the IL method body of the setter to find which field it's setting